# sendgrid email via X-SMTP

Tags: sendgrid

I am trying to figure out how can I make it possible to send an email from my
application to Sendgrid and have it come back.

I want to use coldfusion to send an email using X-SMTP API. I found a documentation 
online here but still wondering if there's any documentation available other 
than the web API one?

http://thehatrack.net/blog/integrating-sendgrid-with-your-coldfusion-application/

Comment: What do you mean by "have it come back"? You can send your email via Sendgrid just by using their SMTP server. That's the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, by have it come back, I mean some sort of response whether the email has been read or not. 

I was wondering some sort of procedure that is mentioned in the above link but not using Web API.

Comment: I don't think there is another way. As far as I know, you have to have a page that SendGrid can post to with the email activity events. It should be simple to implement but I haven't got around to doing it myself yet.

Comment: @acfrancis While exploring, Sendgrid, I have also noticed that sendgrid does sends some responses like, Open, Clicks, Bounce etc. So, I was actually referring to it by saying "have it come back".

Comment: Do you mean through the Event Webhook (http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html)?

Answer (score 5):

SendGrid's [Event Webhook](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html) is the only way to get email reads on an individual basis. This will `POST` an event to your server every time an email is read (among several other events).

The only "pull" based solution to get individual email events from SendGrid is the [`bounces`](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/bounces.html) endpoint, which will tell you when an email bounces (and is certainly not read), but nothing else.

If you want to retrieve individual `read` events from SendGrid, you'll need to connect the Event Webhook to an external service like [Keen.io](https://keen.io), and then [leveraging their API](http://sendgrid.com/blog/extract-analyze-sendgrid-event-data-keen-io/#lookupeventsforaparticularemailoremailaddress) to get individual events.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll check that out. Any idea about where some sort of documentation if it is available using SMTP API rather than Web API mentioned in the documentation link in my question?

Comment: To use SendGrid SMTP with ColdFusion, you'll configure [SMTP as stated in the ColdFusion Docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=email_03.html) with [your SMTP server and credentials set to SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/index.html#-SMTP)